# CSS: SVG Placement In DIV

Tags: css, svg, position

Here's my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/UBHj8/

So my problem is pretty obvious, just can't seem to get the svg to hide the search bar in the right spot. Can someone please help, this little error is driving me nuts.

```
<div class="togglesearch">
    <svg id="hidesearch" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="10" height="10" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
        <polygon points="10,10  10,0  0,5">
    </svg>

    <svg id="showsearch" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="10" height="10" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;">
        <polygon points="0,0  0,10  10,5">
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: where you want to hide your search bar?

Comment: The buttons just toggle the search bar's visibility. My problem is the positioning of the svg when it's visible/shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UBHj8/4/)?

I juste absolute-positioned the svg images in the container, and matched the vertical positions with a padding for the searchbox.

Comment: Thanks bro, I forgot about min-width.